# JS Class Fields

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, class-fields

With ES6 classes, we have getter and setter properties, but no field option (or at least that I know of).

With `Object.defineProperty`, you can set them with the `value` property. If at all, how do you do the same with classes?

I'm aware it can be done in the class constructor, but if possible I'd like for it to be separate.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Can you give an example of how "it can be done in the class constructor" so we can see what you are looking for?

Comment: @lonesomeday In the class constructor, `this.whatever = 'someValue';`

Comment: So you mean object properties? "Class field" is not a concept that exists in JS.

Comment: Yes... They're the same thing regardless of language. @lonesomeday

Comment: Initialisation of instance properties *should* be done in the constructor. What do you think is wrong with that? Why do you want to do it "separate"?

Comment: @Bergi Extending a class. I don't want to create a new constructor in each extended class just to edit the instance properties.

Comment: @Spedwards Every class creates a new constructor anyway, and I don't see any reason why the three lines `constructor(...args) {`, `super(...args),` and `}` would hurt.

Comment: @Bergi You don't need to create a constructor if you're extending one. I'd much rather 1 line than 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say above "they're the same thing regardless of language".

Well, yes and no.

Yes, there are obvious relations between programming languages, but Javascript/ECMAScript has some unusual features. Don't just come in expecting concepts to translate exactly.

The key thing is that Javascript is not class-based, even though it does not have class-like syntax. It is prototype-based. This means you can declare any property on any object. You don't need to include it in a class declaration.

For this reason, "class fields" were not included in the ES6 standard. It was expected that you would include them in the `constructor` method, as is normal in pre-ES6 Javascript.

There is a proposal to create [public class fields](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/). These would look something like this:

```
class Dog {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  bark() {
    console.log('woof');
  }
  tail = new Tail()
}
```

You could then have code that looked like this:

```
let benji = new Dog('Benji');
let rover = new Dog('Rover');
console.log(benji.bark === rover.bark); // true
console.log(benji.tail === rover.tail); // false
```

The key thing is that every "instance" has the same method. However, each "instance" has a different property. This is the distinction that explains why this syntax was not originally included.

As a proposal this is not currently supported. It can be used using transpilation, however. Babel.js (with, as I write, the Stage 2 preset transpiles the above code into this:

```
class Dog {
  constructor(name) {
    this.tail = new Tail();

    this.name = name;
  }
  bark() {
    console.log('woof');
  }
}
```

Comment: Where does the `name` in your transpiled code come from?

Comment: @Bergi A slightly later version of my original code. Now corrected.

Comment: Thanks. Makes it even more obvious how pointless class fields are :-)

Comment: @Bergi That was the approximate aim!

Answer (score 0):

[Class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) are now a stage 3 ECMAScript proposal and are already supported in current versions of Chrome and in Node.js 12. The proposal also references [static fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features).

```
class MyClass {
    static createdObjects = 0;
    objectNumber = MyClass.createdObjects++;
}
```